# Extraction of kernel from Generative model?

Tags: algorithms

I have been working on a project where I am supposed to combine a generative and a discriminative model by exploiting their geometrical feature.
There is a method where you encode the generative information in the kernel and then use this kernel in a discriminative method.
I can't find a method on how to create a generative kernel.Can someone help me how to get generative kernel?I am using ***EEG Eye State*** from UCI repository.